# Dimensions attribute depending Locale Identifier

Tags: ssas, olap

I want to know if it is possible to show different dimensions attributes depending the locale identifier.

That is the connection string using ADOMD.NET.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Catalogo;Data Source=SQlserver;Locale Identifier="+language;
```

For example if I connect with language = 3082(ES), I want to show only one dimensions attribute, and if y change the language i will show another.

Answer (score 0):

Translations inside Analysis Services let the cube developer define the Spanish (and other languages) translations for metadata and the actual dimension member names. Is that what you want? Or do you want to trim down the list of dimension members a user sees based upon the language of their computer?

I don't know of a way of easily retrieving the current Locale Identifier on the current connection. Maybe a .NET sproc that runs inside SSAS would let you figure this out, but I'm not sure I'd recommend that.

I tried creating a role in the Adventure Works sample cube which uses this expression for the Dimension Data security on the [Geography].[Country] attribute:

```
Filter([Geography].[Country].[Country].Members,[Geography].[Country].CurrentMember.Name = [Geography].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Caption)
```

That code is just a conceptual test not something you'd use as is. That code, if it worked, would only let a user see any countries where the translated name (Member_Caption) matches the English name. For example, in the Adventure Works cube, Canada is the english name and Canada is also the Spanish translated name for the country. But that code didn't work because I believe the translations aren't in effect at this point in the connection when the role based security is applied.

So I'm struggling to see how you can accomplish what you're wanting. Maybe someone else will have an idea.